# Buffer too small of SecKeyWrapper, how to solve it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, aes

see my code:

```
  NSString *requestString = @"I am an encrypted piece of dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
NSData *xmlDaCriptare1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length:[requestString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


xmlDaCriptare1 = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *strcheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlDaCriptare1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", strcheck);

char *keya = "a16byteslongkey!";

NSData * symmetricKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:keya length:16];      
CCOptions pad = kCCOptionECBMode;  
NSData *xmlCriptato = [[SecKeyWrapper sharedWrapper] doCipher:xmlDaCriptare1  
                                                key:symmetricKey  
                                            context:kCCEncrypt 
                                            padding:&pad];
```

It always return:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Problem with encipherment ccStatus == -4301'
```

That's "Buffer too small". Anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks,
Alleria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, you have

```
NSData *xmlDaCriptare1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length:[requestString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but the do this which recreates the exact same bytes in your NSData

```
xmlDaCriptare1 = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

your *strcheck* from

```
NSString *strcheck = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlDaCriptare1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

is never released,

I assume you are using **SecKeyWrapper** from this demo sample from apple [CryptoExercise](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m-DontLinkElementID_17), so you may have found a bug in there code (this is just a demo program after all), I suggest you find out where in **SecKeyWrapper** its failing, and if you can not still se what is going wrong post that part of the code.

Comment: Thanks guy. I tried to see the code but without success. The method is  - (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText key:(NSData *)symmetricKey context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt padding:(CCOptions *)pkcs7 {